# Expected prediction error pointwise minimization

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

I am reading "The elements of statistical learning" book by Hastie and have one question about the expected prediction error. He defines it as the following function (section 2.4):
$$\mathrm{EPE}(f) = \mathrm{E}_{X,Y}L(Y,f(X)),$$
where $L$ is a loss function and $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ is a hypothesis.
In case of $L_2$-loss, he wrote that

[image: L2 loss]

Similarly, in case of categorical variable $G$, output space $\mathcal{G} = \{\mathcal{G}_1, \ldots, \mathcal{G}_K \}$ and hypothesis $\hat G: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{G}$, he wrote:

[image: 0-1 loss p.1]
[image: 0-1 loss p.2]

**I want to know, is the following expression correct for any loss $L$** (assuming we have some hypothesis space $\mathcal{H} = \{f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y} \}$):
$$ f(x) = \operatorname*{argmin}_{f \in \mathcal{H}} \mathrm{E}_{Y|X}[L(Y,f(X))| X=x] = \operatorname*{argmin}_{c \in \mathcal{Y}} \mathrm{E}_{Y|X}[L(Y,c)| X=x], \quad \forall x \in \mathcal{X} ~~?$$
**In other words, can we replace functional minimization $(f \in \mathcal{H})$ by scalar minimization $(c \in \mathcal{Y})$ here?** It looks like Hastie did this in (2.12) and (2.21), but I'm not sure. He didn't say any words about the hypothesis space...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea in spirit, but there is no magic in replacing the functional minimization with a scalar minimization. In particular, the middle part of the equation you wrote,
$$
f(x) = \operatorname*{argmin}_{f \in \mathcal{H}} \mathrm{E}_{Y|X}[L(Y,f(X))| X=x],
$$
does not type-check, so to speak. The left-hand side is a *single point* in $\mathcal{Y}$, whereas the right-hand side is a function $f \in \mathcal{H}$, so the equation does not technically make sense.

In Hastie et al.'s formulation, supervised learning is a search for the function $f$ that minimizes the expected loss. This problem can be can be reduced to the task of finding, for each $x \in \mathcal{X}$, the value
$$
\operatorname*{argmin}_{c \in \mathcal{Y}} \mathrm{E}_{Y|X}[L(Y,c)| X=x],
$$
because this then fully specifies $f$. In practice, this optimization problem is impossible, since we don't know the true conditional distribution of $Y|X$. Instead of a general optimization over the entire function space $\{f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y} \}$, we choose a narrowly defined hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ (e.g., the set of linear classifiers), and minimize an empirical loss function over a concrete dataset.

Comment: In other words, Hastie replaces task $\displaystyle f^* = \operatorname*{argmin}_{f \in \mathcal{H}} \mathrm{E}_{X,Y}[L(Y,f(X))]$ by the following set of tasks: $\displaystyle f^*(x) = \operatorname*{argmin}_{c \in \mathcal{Y}} \mathrm{E}_{Y|X}[L(Y,c)| X=x], \forall x \in \mathcal{X}$.    
Well, but can we always be sure that such optimal function $f^*$ (solution of the pointwise task) exists in $\mathcal{H}$? I mean, are there some general requirements on $\mathcal{H}$? Unfortunately, I didn't find information about this in Hastie's book.

Comment: I see what your concern is. I've edited my answer to be a little clearer. I think the thing to realize is that Hastie hasn't introduced the notion of a hypothesis class yet, because at this point in the book we're still dealing with an idealization of the learning problem: _What should we do if we had perfect information?_

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now these things became a bit clearer for me. But I want to add some thoughts about this topic, which are too long for comment. So I decided to write them in a separate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **tddevlin** for your answer, now these things became a bit clearer for me. But I want to add some thoughts about this topic, which are too long for comment. So I decided to write them here.

I should note, that instead of using empirical risk we can also simply take the aforementioned "ideal" results
(*Kevin Murphy in his book, section 5.7, calls them "Bayes estimators" because they minimize Bayesian posterior expected loss; and there is one subtle thing: Murphy writes that the bayesian estimation is done over some "action space" $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. our hypothesis $f$ is a map $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{A}$, but as tddevlin pointed out in the post above,  we shoold choose $\mathcal{A} \equiv \mathcal{Y}$, i.e. consider the entire function space*)
and then just plug-in some estimation of conditional density into them. I mean algorithms such as Naive Bayes classifier. As one more example, Murphy in his book wrote about MMSE gaussian linear regression model: $\hat f(x) = \mathrm{E}[Y|X=x, \mathcal{D}] = x^T \mathrm{E}[w|D], ~ \forall x \in \mathcal{X}$, where we plug-in the posterior mean parameter estimate for $w$.